# TextView above two ListViews

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout, textview

I want to have a TextView above my two ListViews. That's my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent">


<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/statusBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/leftView" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/rightView" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Everything worked well before I added the TextView. Now only the TextView is visible and the two ListViews aren't shown anymore.

Edit: I want to have the ListViews still next to each other (one left, the other right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the orientation of the `LinearLayout` to vertical

```
android:orientation="vertical"

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_width="match_parent">


<TextView 
android:id="@+id/statusBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Test" />



<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:id="@+id/rightView" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_width="0dip">
</ListView>

 <ListView
     android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:id="@+id/leftView" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_width="0dip">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. Now the ListViews are shown. But one below the other. I want to have one of them left and the other right.

Comment: Thanks. That works. But I get a warning: "Nested weights are bad for performance".

Comment: remove the weight property from the LinearLayout.